# Image upload as b64 string using tag helpers in ASP.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, base64, tag-helpers

Hi guys I need to send an image as an encoded b64 string among other filled values in the form.

I know I can do an Ajax - post but is there any way to use tag helpers to do the same.

Here is the form:

```
<form class="form-padding" method="post">
  <a href="#"><img src=".." id="image"></a>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" asp-for="ImageUrl" id="dp-upload" onchange="readURL(this);">
       <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
       <input asp-for="FirstName" />
       <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
       <input asp-for="LastName" />
       <label asp-for="Address">Address</label>
       <input asp-for="Address"  />
      <button type="submit">Add </button>
</form>
<script>
          function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#dp-upload').attr('val', e.target.result);
                debugger
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

<script>
```

I am trying to find out if there is a way with tag helpers where I can send the image as a base 64 encoded string.

Also I tried to get the full path of the uploaded file so that I can convert it to a base 64 string in the controller.

But, I am getting only the image name.

Direction needed:)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible, and it's unclear why you'd want to. Assuming this is doing a tradition HTML form post, you'd bind the upload field to a property of type `IFormFile`. That then gives you access to the stream, which you can convert to Base64 if you like, after the fact:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var fs = model.ImageUpload.OpenReadStream())
{
    await fs.CopyToAsync(ms);
    model.ImageUrl = $"data:{model.ImageUpload.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())}";
}
```

For what it's worth, you should avoid data URIs, especially for user upload files. There's two issues with data URIs that dramatically affect page performance:

1. They're delivered inline with the HTML content, which means it will take longer to download the page and longer for the browser to parse and render it. Let's say your HTML document is 1KB and you have a 50KB image. As a data URI, the browser is downloading all 51KB at once, and can only start rendering once that is complete. As a normal URL, the browser downloads the 1KB document and immediately starts rendering, filling in the image when it finally arrives. This situation grows exponentially worse the more images you're including on the page in this way. For an image heavy site, you could easily force multi-megabyte downloads before the browser can do anything.
2. Base64 is a very-inefficient encoding. It can balloon image sizes 150% or more. So if your image is 50KB, the Base64-encoded version of it will be likely 75KB. Again, the more you do this, the more weight you're adding to your page. And, combined with point #1 above, you're exasperating an already big problem.

Data URIs are best reserved for very small simple images, like an icon or something. When you start using them with things like photos, you're going to have big problems. The fact that you're allowing user-uploads, means you can't even fully control how big the data URIs will even be, unless you restrict upload size to something minuscule. By default a user can upload up to 2MB files. That could then mean you're sending 3MB or more inline with your HTML document, which is frankly just insane. You can of course resize or compress the user upload images to make them smaller, but you need to actually remember to do that.